# msbuild - what are rules for scope/inheritance of properties/items?

Tags: msbuild

I have the following definitions in my working msbuild project...

```
<MSBuild
        Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"
        Condition="'@(FilesToCompile)' != ''"
        Targets="buildcpp"
        Properties="CPPFILE=%(FilesToCompile.FullPath);OBJFILE=$(ObjectFolder)\%(FilesToCompile.Filename).doj;IncludeDirs=$(IncludeDirs)"
    />
```

...followed by the definition of the target.
Notice how the definition of the target contains a call to another target `compilecpp`...

```
<Target Name="buildcpp">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <CompileDefines Condition="'$(PreprocessorDefinitions)' != ''">-D$(PreprocessorDefinitions.Replace(";"," -D"))</CompileDefines>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec
        EchoOff="true"
        StandardOutputImportance="low"
        StandardErrorImportance="low"
        IgnoreExitCode="true"
        ConsoleToMSBuild="true" 
        Command='
            "$(CompilerExe)" ^
                $(HWProcessor) ^
                $(IncludeDirs) ^
                $(CompilerOptions) ^
                $(CompileDefines) ^
                "$(CPPFILE)" ^
                -MM
    '>
        <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="output_cppdeps"/>
        <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="exitcode_cppdeps"/>
    </Exec>

<MSBuild
        Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"
    Condition="'$(exitcode_cppdeps)' == '0'"
        Targets="compilecpp"
        Properties="INPUTFILES=$(BuildCppDeps)"     
    />
</Target>
```

...which uses the property `$(OBJFILE)` even though it was never passed in by the caller

```
<Target Name="compilecpp" Inputs="$(INPUTFILES)" Outputs="$(OBJFILE)">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="$(CPPFILE): Compiling..."/>
...
```

**QUESTION**

Since this msbuild works, I can infer that `$(OBJFILE)` is accessible; why is it accessible? What are the scope rules for properties?

Comment: MSBuild/ClallTarget tasks inherit all global properties. Not sure exactly where this is in the official documentation but it's here for example: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaronhallberg/2007/07/16/msbuild-property-evaluation/

Comment: @stijn by `global properties` do you mean all the properties that existed at the time of the `MSBuild/CallTarget` call?

Comment: Yes. Actually if you run msbuild (command line or task) with verbosity set to diagnostic it will output all properties it knows. Can be quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `<MSBuild>` task, this performs a new msbuild run similar to running `msbuild.exe` with arguments. In particular, passing in properties is similar to passing `/p:PropName=Value` arguments - it defines new "global properties" for this run.

During this inner build, the property is still there and accessible by additional inner builds (buildcpp -> compilecpp) unless overwritten. So `OBJFILE` is only accessible in `compilecpp` because it was defined as global property for a parent msbuild run. If `compilecpp` was somehow invoked directly, the property would not be defined (assuming it not set somewhere else). When you want to stop forwarding a global property, you'd need to use the MSBuild task's `RemoveProperties` parameter. So if you set `RemoveProperties="OBJFILE"`, then it won't be pased on.

Fyi, in .NET Core projects, `RemoveProperties` is used to not forward a `RuntimeIdentifier` from a self-contained apps to referenced projects, which may not be able to build with this property set (due to missing restore information).

For more information, read the [properties documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties) - especially the section about global properties - and the [MSBuild Task documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task) (important part is the description for the `Properties` parameter). However, the fact that global properties are passed on isn't explicitly documented (though implied by the `RemoveProperties`).

**Update:** the [documentation for global properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties#global-properties) was updated to describe this behavior:

> Global properties are also forwarded to child projects unless the
>   RemoveProperties attribute of the MSBuild task is used to specify the
>   list of proerties not to forward.

Comment: Do you happen to know where this is stated in the official docs?

Comment: Yeah I know those, but they don't say anywhere that a project ran via the MSBuild task (what you call 'inner build') inherits the parent properties, right?

Comment: Ture, it doesn't say that they are forwarded. The documentation of `RemoveProperties` implies it though. Very helpful :( - however, this is how it is implemented and how passing any custom properties to a solution build has always worked.

Comment: Opened a PR for the global properties doc: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/pull/343

Comment: Ok that's nice!